# Do A and B reach home at the same time in this question?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

[image]

According to me they don't reach their respective homes P and Q at the same time because the points at which they reach their home clearly don't coincide. Yet the solution given is that they reach their homes at the same time. How is this possible? It looks like A takes more time to reach than B.

I was able to solve the rest of the questions given correctly except this one. So, is the solution that they have given is  wrong or is there some correct explanation for the given solution?

Source : NCERT Physics textbook for Grade 11. Chapter 3 (Motion In A Straight Line), question number : 3.2)

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. Either there is a misprint in your book or clearly they don't reach home at same time.